# Getting minimum records can occupy the specific value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Having the following `Cars` table in `PostgreSQL`

| car_no | order_in_queue | max_passengers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 1 | 3 |
| 2222 | 2 | 2 |
| 3333 | 3 | 5 |
| 4444 | 4 | 1 |
| 5555 | 5 | 4 |

I need to write a `SQL Statement` in `PostgreSQL` retrieve a `minimum number of cars` that can occupy a `specific number of passengers` while `maintaining the car order in the queue`

**For Example**:

- If I have 6 passengers, I have to retrieve the cars `111,222,333`
- If I have 4 passengers, I have to retrieve the cars `111,222`
- If I have 11 passengers, I have to retrieve the cars `111,222,333,444`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, leveraging `SUM` as an analytic function to do the rolling sum:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(max_passengers) OVER (ORDER BY order_in_queue)
                  - max_passengers rolling_sum
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT car_no, order_in_queue, max_passengers
FROM cte
WHERE rolling_sum < 11    -- or replace with desired number of passengers
ORDER BY order_in_queue;
```

Comment: If you subtract current `max_passengers` from running sum and change where to `where rolling_sum < 11`, the desired output can be retrieved directly from the first CTE without subquery.